# How to get position in ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

I have a question how to get "position" in ArrayList. I don´t mean position of element. Well, i have java class for ArrayList called QiuzModal.java like this:

```
public class QuizModal {
    private String question;
    private String option1;
    private String option2;
    private String option3;
    private String option4;
    private String answer;
    private String typingAnswer;

    public QuizModal(String question, String option1, String option2, String option3, String option4, String answer, String typingAnswer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.option1 = option1;
        this.option2 = option2;
        this.option3 = option3;
        this.option4 = option4;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.typingAnswer = typingAnswer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getOption1() {
        return option1;
    }

    public void setOption1(String option1) {
        this.option1 = option1;
    }

    public String getOption2() {
        return option2;
    }

    public void setOption2(String option2) {
        this.option2 = option2;
    }

    public String getOption3() {
        return option3;
    }

    public void setOption3(String option3) {
        this.option3 = option3;
    }

    public String getOption4() {
        return option4;
    }

    public void setOption4(String option4) {
        this.option4 = option4;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getTypingAnswer() {
        return typingAnswer;
    }

    public void setTypingAnswer(String typingAnswer) {
        this.typingAnswer = typingAnswer;
    }
}
```

and I am adding questions to the ArrayList this way:

```
quizModalArrayList.add(new QuizModal("Which color is red ?","cyklamen","white","red","purple","red", null));
quizModalArrayList.add(new QuizModal("How many days does one year have ?", null, null, null, null, "365","365"));
```

So, I don´t need to find out on which position is for example question about days in a year. I need to find out position of option2 in added question
[image]
And also to find out if is there any way to set something to that position (for example NULL) if the question doesn´t have options.

Comment: Hi, do you want to get the property  position  of the object `QuizModal` that adding to the `ArrayList`?

Comment: By the way, spelling "modal" versus "model", two different words.

Comment: Hi, basically yes if it is possible because i need to know where set NULL if it's needed when I will not enter questions and options manually but for example from a file or from some database

Comment: That's just a typo i made and haven't fix yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
 private String option1;
 private String option2;
 private String option3;
 private String option4;
```

You may want this:

`private List<String> options;`

You can populate it:

```
quizModalArrayList.add(new QuizModal("Which color is red ?",Arrays.asList("cyklamen","white","red","purple"),"red", null));
```

That way, you would be able to find which option is where and have it more flexible.

Comment: If I use private List<String> options how will it change this: quizModalArrayList.add(new QuizModal("Which color is red ?","cyklamen","white","red","purple","red", null));  ?

Comment: `quizModalArrayList.add(new QuizModal("Which color is red ?",Arrays.asList("cyklamen","white","red","purple"),"red", null));`